# How to get from MNA system of equations to state-space [A,B,C,D] mimo in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, state-space

I want to programatically generate state-space [A B C D] system from a generated MNA (modified nodal analysis) system of equations. I don't know which MATLAB functions to call.

I use the SCAM [link](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA1.html) script from Erik Cheever to generate the system of equations.

I made file example3.cir [link](http://vanrens.i234.me/files/stacko/example3.cir) which is a spice RLC circuit with input source Vs.

I also tried netlist2linss [link](https://github.com/bencholmes/netlist2linss) github but it is not in laplace domain and it does not work correctly.

```
example3.cir:
R1 2 1 R
C1 3 0 C
L1 2 3 L
Vs 1 0 V

>> fname = 'example3.cir'; scam; system_of_eqns = [Z == A*X]
Solved variables:
v_1
v_2
v_3
I_Vs

system_of_eqns =
                      0 == I_Vs + v_1/R1 - v_2/R1
 0 == v_2*(1/R1 + 1/(L1*s)) - v_1/R1 - v_3/(L1*s)
          0 == v_3*(C1*s + 1/(L1*s)) - v_2/(L1*s)
                                        Vs == v_1

>> [A_,b_] = equationsToMatrix(system_of_eqns, X)

A_ =
[ -1/R1,              1/R1,                 0, -1]
[  1/R1, - 1/R1 - 1/(L1*s),          1/(L1*s),  0]
[     0,          1/(L1*s), - C1*s - 1/(L1*s),  0]
[    -1,                 0,                 0,  0]

b_ =
0
0
0
-Vs
```

expected (capacitor voltage as output):

```
A =
[     0,  1/C1 ]
[ -1/L1, -R/L1 ]

B =
[ 0, 1/L1 ]

C =
[ 1, 0 ]

D = 
[ 0 ]

states = [sVC1 sIL1]

input =  [ Vs ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in python called lcapy:
https://github.com/mph-/lcapy